# Performance tracing in C#

Tags: c#, performance, logging, mobile, trace

I would like to trace performance inside a c# mobile application, in order to know the amount of time needed by some long-running methods. The goal is to know the performance at the level of methods. This tracing would be decided at runtime.

First idea that came is to maintain a global variable "doWeHaveToTrace", to check it each time a potentially traceable method is called, and trace it if that variable is true. And in this case, I probably would use a Logger or a TraceListener to write tracing infos into a file.

But I think this mechanism is quite heavy, because a variable has to be checked in each method, and the logger calls have to be coded.

I also thought about aspect programming (insert tracing code in `before()` and `after()` methods), but I don't think aspect programming could be allowed inside this project.

So I was wondering, is there any other good mechanisms that could provide such performance tracing ? Is it possible to trace a whole method ? And to decide to stop or resume tracing at runtime ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to trace, but if you're trying to track time between long running methods, perhaps you'd be better off hooking into the [.NET Profiling API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384358.aspx).  Here is a [tutorial on usage.](http://www.blong.com/Conferences/DCon2003/Internals/Profiling.htm)

A commerical profiler would be another, simpler option.

Answer (score 0):

Read about how to [Compile Conditionally with Trace and Debug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64yxa344.aspx) in .NET (assuming you are using .NET). The **Trace** and **Debug** classes will provide you with all the run-time output you need for development purposes. Then you can remove all your debug/trace code (and the associated run-time overhead) in your deployed application simply by removing the TRACE compiler directives.

**OR**

You can use an **external profiling application** to do your performance and memory profiling. See here (from StackOverflow.com): [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)

Answer (score 0):

Can you just run it on a desktop machine, under an IDE, and do the usual things, like clocking it and/or [sampling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024)

You're bound to find things that are taking time and could be speeded up.